# How can i call A wpf form in my winform Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I m Developing A Desktop project in C# using Window Form and i want to Add Some WPf Form in this Project I just Want to know that Can i Call this Form Directly or there is need to  integrate all  these form in Win form And After that i call..
please help me out

thanks in advance

shashank

Answer (score 0):

That's just not going to work well. You should really make up your mind wether you want to go Winforms or WPF. Mixing both architectures is just calling for trouble. Personally I'd go WPF any day.